# how to turn off GIT_CURL_VERBOSE?

Tags: git, config

so ever since I set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 now everytime I upload something it gives me long paragraphs of unneeded details. How can I unset this variable/turn off the logging?

Answer (score 8):

Set the value to `0`:

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=0
```

If that doesn't solve it for you (on some installations, `git` seems to check only whether the variable is set, not what its value has), instead try

```
unset GIT_CURL_VERBOSE
```

(or open a new shell without the variable declared at all).

Answer (score 1):

What Gergo wrote works if you are using git bash.

If you are not but entering the commands for git in the cmd prompt instead, you should try to restart the cmd prompt and use the command Gergo wrote.

Comment: while the OP did make his or herself clear, this response does little to add to this.  It would help your answer considerably (and for others who read it) if you explained it a little more.

Comment: Thank you. I explained a little more detailled.